# Handle large data object, should release Clob?

Tags: java, jdbc, resources, resultset, clob

I'm using Oracle database with `ojdbc7` driver
I'm getting Clob from ResultSet using `(Clob)rs.getObject("DATA")` and then I'm convert it to String in method:

```
private String clobToString(Clob data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (Reader reader = data.getCharacterStream(); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)){
        String line;
        while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to read CLOB", e);         
    }    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

According to Oracle's [Using Large Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html)

> Blob, Clob, and NClob Java objects remain valid for at least the duration of the transaction in which they are created. This could potentially result in an application running out of resources during a long running transaction. Applications may release Blob, Clob, and NClob resources by invoking their free method.
>
> In the following excerpt, the method Clob.free is called to release the resources held for a previously created Clob object

Should I add more code to release in `finally`:

```
    finally {
        try {
            data.free();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to release Clob", e);
        }
    }
```

Or is it insignificant addition because `Clob` isn't used outside method or is there a simple/native way of getting a String from large object from database?

Comment: You are using try with resources statement, so  I don't see that finally block is important here

Comment: @YCF_L `Clob`/`SerialClob` is not `AutoCloseable` so it won't effect it

Comment: I'm not fully sure, but can you try this way, `StringBuilder r = rs.getObject("DATA", StringBuilder.class);`

Comment: @YCF_L Exception `org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: Not supported yet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the clob isn't used outside that method doesn't imply that calling `free()` is unuseful: if you don't call it you are delaying the release of resources *at least until the transaction ends* (as Oracle's doc says).
This is also discussed in [Do java.sql.Array/Blob/Clob types need to be "free()"ed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362726/do-java-sql-array-blob-clob-types-need-to-be-freeed) and [Should JDBC Blob (not) be free()'d after use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830047/should-jdbc-blob-not-be-freed-after-use) and [JDBC 4's java.sql.Clob.free() method and backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684438/jdbc-4s-java-sql-clob-free-method-and-backwards-compatibility)

About simple/native way of getting a String from clob, see [Most efficient solution for reading CLOB to String, and String to CLOB in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java)

Comment: There are many answers and most voted answers ignore `free`ing the clob, can you add your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, in the last page they focus on reading, not freeing, however you should `free()` the clob.